# Adding an admob causes an error that does not exist. error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lt@777a78f

Tags: java, android, service, admob, illegalargumentexception

To use the Admob.

`Implementation 'com.Google.android.gms:play-services-adds:19.2.0'`

I added this part. I added Menifest.

(I've filed an official Admob document. )

Sample advertisement is also good. But the error message below kept coming up.
There is no big problem or the app turns off..

```
2020-07-23 13:45:00.483 4068-4318/net.goldensize.bitthumbauto W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lt@777a78f
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1870)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1848)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:755)
        at cg.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414081@20.24.14 (120400-0):1)
        at cg.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414081@20.24.14 (120400-0):6)
        at lu.A(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414081@20.24.14 (120400-0):10)
        at lf.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414081@20.24.14 (120400-0):3)
        at dz.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414081@20.24.14 (120400-0):3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at ja.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414081@20.24.14 (120400-0):6)
```

I was wondering if it was a conflict with the old code. so
**Create an empty project with a new project.**

Added admob to empty project.
The same error occurs.

`Implementation 'com.Google.android.gms:play-services-adds:19.2.0`

If you just write the part where you add the Admob... The same error is generated.

In this case, has anyone tried debugging?

Comment: Same problem. You find solution? Also its AdMob not Edmob

Comment: @이우진 I had basic discussion on this issue here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390472/android-service-not-registered-error-how-i-can-find-where-error?noredirect=1#comment113878786_64390472) Check out it might help in your case.

Comment: Also experiencing this with Mobile Ads SDK versions down to `17.2.0`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62217275/android-foreground-service-consistently-throws-java-lang-illegalargumentexcepti

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me slightly insane until I noticed that I include Firebase in my `build.gradle` as follows:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
...
```

Android Studio build.gradle was **not** prompting me to update to the latest version:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
```

After making this update, and checking back to confirm with the previous version, the warning has disappeared.

I think firebase may integrate some of the core Google libraries, so possibly the same fix will be obtained simply by updating your `com.google.android.gms:play-services-xxx` libraries

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: It did not solve my problem. Btw, how did you come to know that its version has been updated?(since studio doesn't warn)

Comment: I chanced upon it. (far from ideal, I know)  Sorry to hear that it hasn't fixed your problem.